# How to run a php query in index.php but with friendlier URLs?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, uri, friendly-url

I want to type `www.mysite.com/page1` in the browser

but I want the server to get this.
`www.mysite.com/index.php?page=1`

and I want the former address `www.mysite.com/page1` to stay persistent in the browser address bar. Is this possible?

I assume it's a mod rewrite but I really have trouble with that file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess I should have mentioned that "page1", "page2", etc could really be any string - so it could be "gorilla" or "astronaut" or "icecream". I see in my .htaccess I already have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]`

Comment: If you have a `www.mysite.com/gorlla` what do you internal server URL to be since now you don't have any page # as in the case of `page1`, `page2` etc.

Comment: Basically, I would want www.mysite.com/gorilla to become www.mysite.com/index.php?page=gorilla

Comment: Ok got it, answer updated to make it `/index.php?page=gorilla`